# Torsion Module has Finite Length (from Liu)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I have a question about an argument in the proof of Proposition 7.1.38 from Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" (page 263):

[image]

We have two Noetherian rings $A, B=O_{X}(X)$ with fraction fields $K(Y)=\operatorname{Frac}(A)$, $K(X)=\operatorname{Frac}(B)$.

Since $[K(X):K(Y)]=n $ finite $K(X)$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $K(Y)$ generated by $b_1,..., b_n \in B$.

Therefore $K(X)= \langle b_1,..., b_n \rangle_{K(Y)}$.

We set $M:= \sum_{1 \le i \le n} Ab_i$

By construction $B/M$ is a ***torsion*** $A$-module.

My QUESTION is why does this already imply that $B/M$ has ***finite [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_of_a_module)*** as $A$-module?

Comment: If $N$ is a finitely generated torsion $A$-module, then $\operatorname{Ann}_A(N)\ne 0$. Since $A$ is an integral domain with $\dim A=1$ we have that $A/\operatorname{Ann}_A(N)$ is artinian, so $N$ is an artinian $A/\operatorname{Ann}_A(N)$-module, and hence an artinian $A$-module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point $y$ is a point of codimension 1. Hence $\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}) = 1$. So $\mathrm{dim}(A) = 1$ and recall that $A$ is local. It has only one non-zero prime ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

Any finitely generated $A$-module $M$ has a sequence of submodules $ 0 = M_0 \subset M_1 \subset \cdots \subset M_n = M$ such that $M_i/M_{i-1}$ is isomorphic to $A/\mathfrak{p}_i$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_i$ of $A$ (for reference of this fact, see Serre, Local Algebra, I, corrolary 2).

Let now $M$ be a torsion $A$-module. Given the structure of $A$, the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ are either $0$ or $\mathfrak{m}$. If any of the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ is $0$, then, $M$ would have a torsion-free element. So all of the $\mathfrak{p}_i$s are $\mathfrak{m}$ and the sequence is a composition series for $M$. By definition, the existence of such a series means that $M$ is of finite length.

Comment: ah ok so the point where the torsion assumption play the essential role is that if $M$ would be not torsion free there could occure quotients $M_i/M_{i-1} \cong A$ and $A$ could (for example if $A$ is not Artinian) have infinite lenght as $A$ module,right? While $A/m$ are always simple.

Comment: @KarlPeter Yes. Actually $A$ is never Artinian in this case since it is of dimension 1 and an artinian ring must have dimension 0.